# ionCube Not working on my system

Tags: php, ioncube

I am using

**PHP Version 5.5.12**

and

**ioncube_loader_win_5.5.dll** or **ioncube_loader_win_5.6.dll**

This is not working on my window system I am using same steps as per

http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-admin/howto-installing-ioncube

When I am checking this in local system then its showing

```
C:\Users\abc>php -v
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2014 11:20:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with the ionCube PHP Loader v10.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

its fine but its not working on my application.

When I am checking by

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

Then its showing me correct value in array [56] => ionCube Loader

**Error: The file C:\wamp\www\abc\application\bootstrap.php is corrupted.**

And

```
Fatal error: <br>The file <b>C:\wamp\www\abc\application\bootstrap.php</b> was encoded with the PHP 5.6 ionCube Encoder and requires PHP 5.6 to be installed. in Unknown on line 0
```

So please provide exact solution

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache ? `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: Which framework your using Symfony ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave we are using Kohana thanks

Comment: Website working fine on live serve its only giving me problem on my local system.

Comment: Have you actually read and thought about the error message?
... requires PHP 5.6 to be installed

Comment: I have used PHP 5.6 AND 7 but getting same error

Comment: If you are using PHP 5.6 and the Loader for PHP 5.6 is installed, you would not be getting the same error, and most likely the code would be working. Note that contrary to the error message, you could also use the files on PHP 7.0 if you are using PHP 7.0 and the Loader for PHP 7.0 is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing right and appropriate IonCube Loader package is important. IonCube's wizard loader helps you to find right loader package for you, according to your system configuration. So I recommend you to install IonCube Loader using Wizard Loader.

If you want to find more information is a detailed article on how to [install IonCube Loader in localhost](https://www.myprogrammingtutorials.com/install-ioncube-loader-localhost.html)